# Filter out region names from a list of countries and regions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

A list contains all countries of the world plus names of regions, continents, etc. Is there a more elegant way of filtering out the non-country names other than manually?

One solution is manually filtering the names, but that seems...overly manual?

None

Names such as Latin America & the Caribbean, Western Africa, and North America need to be in their own list.

Comment: Please add what code have you tried so far for this question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize yourself with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- (2) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to provide some more details and code example for someone to assist you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly provide some sample data as it is unclear from the description that you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Let's assume your list is called `my_list`.

Using [`pycountry`](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) package:

```py
import pycountry

coutries = []

for country in list(pycountry.countries):
    countries.append(country)  # Creates a list full of official country names

# Print all the names which are not in countries but are un my_list
print([country for country not in countries and country in my_list])
```

Comment: thank you, the first part of your response plus the following led me to the desired result: regions_not_in_countries_list = countries.symmetric_difference(regions_not_in_countries_list).intersection(regions_not_in_countries_list)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, could you upvote and mark my answer as the solution?